# Can you setup both Pi-Hole and PfSense on one Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3b+, pi-hole

I am using a Raspberry Pi 3B+ and I would like to setup PfSense and Pi-Hole on the same device. Is that possible? Any guidelines would be appreciated.

Comment: Never tried but no reason why not (off the top of my head).  I would look to using two adapters for PfSense to isolate external from internal and maybe using Docker.  It may be best to ask on the Pi-Hole discord forum to see if this is any better solution than pfBlockerNG https://protectli.com/kb/how-to-setup-pfblockerng/

Comment: @Andyroo thanks for the link. Does RPi support Docker well tho? How is virtualization on RPi in general?

Comment: TBH - neither are questions for comments :-) and both will lead to subjective answers and get closed as a guess. Esxi is now out - give it a go for the full Pi VM experience.